# upgrade to angular 5 - get an error TS2307: Cannot find module './compiled/app/app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: angular, aot

I have updated our app from angular 4 to angular 5 and when I run "yarn run start" command I get en error error TS2307: Cannot find module './compiled/app/app.module.ngfactory' ./main.ts.

We are using gulp and webpack.

In the webpack config I use the AngularCompilerPlugin like that:

const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;

here is the packages.json file

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp build:dev",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.3",
    "npm": "4.0.5"
  },
  "license": "LicenseRef-LICENSE",
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "url": "git+ssh://gitolite@git:App"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "1.3.0",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "0.3.4",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "jasmine": "2.8.0",
    "jstz": "1.0.9",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.13",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "xlsx": "0.11.7",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.8.0",
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.6",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "custom-tslint-formatters": "2.0.0",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-add-src": "0.2.0",
    "gulp-cache-bust": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-exec": "2.1.3",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "3.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "2.0.2",
    "gulp-ignore": "2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "3.1.1",
    "gulp-jsonminify": "1.0.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "6.3.0",
    "gulp-preprocess": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "3.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.4.1",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "1.3.6",
    "gulp-tslint": "7.1.0",
    "gulp-util": "3.0.8",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.2.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-typescript": "3.0.8",
    "karma-typescript-es6-transform": "1.0.2",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "1.3.3",
    "postcss-scss": "0.4.1",
    "precss": "1.4.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.1",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "typings": "2.1.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.1"
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowser }    from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from "./compiled/app/app.module.ngfactory";

if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Also tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./compiled",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./compiled",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
    }
}
```

THANK YOU

Comment: Check if your tsconfig.json has the following at the root level:

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "src/ngfactory",
    "entryModule": "./src/app#AppModule"
  }

Comment: @Sajeetharan I wouldn't do it in angular 5. `genDir` is deprecated

Comment: Try `import { AppModuleNgFactory } from "./app/app.module.ngfactory";`

Comment: @yurzui ok! i dint know that

Comment: @Sajeetharan  We should use `outDir` now

Comment: Thank you for you answers.  yurzui I changed from genDir to outDir in angularCompilerOptions and also import the AppModuleNgFactory  from ./app/app.module.ngfactory and it's working!! thank you:)